# Maximum update depth exceeded when used in OnSubmitEditing

Tags: javascript, react-native

Unlike most people with this problem, when I call my function using this.myFunc inside a TextInput's onSubmitEditing I get the maximum update depth error.

I've tried arrow functions vs not, adding .bind and () after the function but nothing fixed this problem

```
  storeData = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(this.state.title, this.state.text);
    } catch (e) {
      // saving error
    }
  };


//other code, render stuff etc.

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Event Due Date"
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({text})}
          onSubmitEditing={
            (() => this.storeData, //this line fires the error
            this.setState({
              display: 'none',
              text: '',
              title: '',
              reminders: (this.state.reminders += 1),
            }))
          }
          value={this.state.text}
          style={[styles.textInput, {display: this.state.display}]}
        />
```

When I remove the this.storeData the setState works perfectly fine but adding the line fires the error. The goal is to have the storeData method execute when the user finishes editing (by clicking the check mark on the keyboard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code might help

```
storeData = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(this.state.title, this.state.text);

      this.setState({
          display: 'none',
          text: '',
          title: '',
          reminders: (this.state.reminders += 1),
        });

    } catch (e) {
      // saving error
    }
  };

onSubmitEdit = () => {
    this.storeData();
}


//other code, render stuff etc.

<TextInput
  placeholder="Event Due Date"
  onChangeText={text => this.setState({text})}
  onSubmitEditing={this.onSubmitEdit} />
  value={this.state.text}
  style={[styles.textInput, {display: this.state.display}]}
/>
```